# Solve on the interval $[0,2\pi)$: $4 \sin(x) \cos(x)=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I tried using the product-to-sum formulas, but did not come up with the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was hinted, $$\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$$
Hence, your equation becomes 
$$2\sin2x=1$$
$$\sin2x=\frac12$$
$$2x=\arcsin\frac12$$
$$2x=\frac\pi6,\,\frac{5\pi}6$$
$$x=\frac\pi{12},\,\frac{5\pi}{12}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: use the double-angle formula for sine:

$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$